# How to Run the TypeScript build in Visual Studio code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling) document to run a hello-world typescript program in Visual Studio Code Editor.

I have done following steps

1. Installed the TypeScript compiler tsc --version shows Version 4.2.4
2. Transpiled TypeScript into JavaScript

When i try to run the type script build, by Executing Run Build Task (⇧⌘B) I DONOT see any task to build in that.

[image]

So I am stuck at this point. Can some one tell me if we need to manually create this task? OR is there a pre-requisite that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio Code

Comment: @MrCodingB Yes, I did restart, but no relief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restarting VSCode. If that doesn't work try configuring the task via:

`Command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P / F1) > Tasks: Configure default build task`

If that doesn't work here are the default task configurations:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {  // For build
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"
        },
        {  // For watch
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "tsc: watch - tsconfig.json"
        },
        { // If both of the above don't work you could create an npm script and run it via this task
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "build", // This should be the name of your script
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: build typescript"
        }
    ]
}
```

For these to be detected create a `.vscode` Folder at the root of your workspace and create a file `tasks.json` in it. If you put the above json in it, VSCode will find your tasks.

Comment: Thanks, can you please also explain a bit where and how to use default task configurations.

Comment: Added a little explanation to my answer

Comment: Thanks so much. A minor suggestion Please also open the command to open the command pallet. Ctrl+Shift+P will bring you directly to the editor commands. I just ran the command you mentioned and was able to build. Thanks!

Comment: Those first two tasks only work right (on WIndows) if VS Code is using the Windows command line interpreter as the shell. The `tsc.js` script detects the OS it's running on and sets the path separator to match it. If you are using a Unix shell, like bash, the path characters disappear into the command and won't find the command being executed.